# jquery .change function making script crash in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, onchange

Hi I was working on jquery `.change` function.

**javascript code :**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#user").change(function()
    {
       var v=$('#user').val();
       var i=0;
       var id1="";
       while(v[i]!="|")
       {
          parseInt(v[i]);
          id1=(id1)+v[i];
          i++;
       }
      $("#dummy").attr("href", "create_graph/demo_graph.php?id="+id1);
      $("#dummy").attr("target",'content1');
  });
```

**HTML code :**

```
User Name:
<TD>
    <SELECT NAME='user' id='user'>
        <OPTION value=''></OPTION>{USER}
    </SELECT>
</TD>
```

It works fine in Mozilla and Chrome, but gives pop up box saying

```
"Stop running this script? 
A script on this page is causing your web browser to run slowly. If it continues to run, your          
computer might become unresponsive. "
```

It gives this pop up box again and again even though i Say "NO"

When I remove above javascript it does not give any popup...

Please help me out. I will provide the required information as needed.

Comment: I just want to make sure. Did you close document.ready function? because i can see only one close parenthesis }).  check that

Comment: `var v=$('#user').val();` how much value do you have in this when you looped through?

Comment: @Jai..my dropdownlist may have values greater than 20.and number of characters in v range from 5-10

Comment: @EdwinAlex..its already closed..i have just pasted the part of my code here

Comment: @nikhil and how do you fill your dropdownlist (in order to be sure that it produces effectively always correct values with a `|` inside of each)?

Answer (score 4):

`v[i]!="|"` will always be true if `v` doesn't contain `|`, so it will be an infinite loop.

You just want get the part before `|`, so you could just use the `split` method:

```
$("#user").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val().split('|')[0];
    $("#dummy").attr("href", "create_graph/demo_graph.php?id="+id);
    $("#dummy").attr("target",'content1');
});
```

Comment: @nikhil Are you sure? I saw an option whose value is empty string. But rather than that, you could just use the `split` method.

Comment: This looks like an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your

```
while(v[i]!="|")
```

might be running forever.  Add a termination condition explicitly.

Comment: v always contain string with "|"
example 1234|4

Comment: I am trying to get it running in jsFiddle, here's the link:

http://jsfiddle.net/bhqcu/

Comment: @SidCool it is rather that : http://jsfiddle.net/Wrmwu/1/ (the HTML code is not filled with values in the OP question).

Comment: Ah, thanks @SamuelCaillerie.  It's working like a charm for the given data.